# How to align the points with specific order and connect them by line within each group on x axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So far the plot was generated as below:

```
id=sort(rep(1:10,3))
visit=rep(c("week1","week2","week3"),10)
set.seed(123)
value=round(rnorm(30,mean=8.3,sd=0.6),2)

df=data.frame(id,factor(visit),value)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(id), y= value, color= visit, group=id))+
  geom_point(size=2, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_line(color="grey",size=0.6,linetype="dashed")
```

[image]

The ultimate goal is to arrange the points of week1, week2, week3 from left to right, and then connect the three points by a line within each id group. I tried the position_dodge(), but it didn't work. So how should I modify the code to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to achieve the look you desire using 'sneaky' facets, with `visit` on the x axis and faceting by ID:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = visit, y = value, color = visit, group = id))+
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line(color = 'gray', linewidth = 0.6, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_x_discrete('ID', breaks = 'week2') +
  facet_grid(.~id, switch = 'x') +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

As an alternative, you could overlay all the IDs in a single panel:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = visit, y = value, color = visit, group = id))+
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line(color = "grey", linewidth = 0.6, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

And perhaps you want to color by `id` to allow individuals to be tracked between visits:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = visit, y = value, color = factor(id), group = id))+
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.6, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_brewer('ID', palette = 'Set3') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]